# Printing a binary tree vertically

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I want to print a binary tree vertically. I know a solution using hashmap. But, I read at many places that it can be done by using a doubly linked list. However, I can not make out how to do so. I could not find any understandable material on the net as well. Can somebody please help me with the doubly linked list method?

Example:

```
        5
    4       3
  6   7   8   9
```

This gives

```
6
4
5 7 8
3
9
```

i.e. it is like a level order traversal in vertical order.

Solution using hash map: Assume that the root is indexed 0, then the left ones will be `-1`, `-2`, etc. and right ones will be `+1`, `+2`, etc. So, we can build a hash keyed on column number and have a list of all the roots that have that particular column number as value. Then we can simply print the entries in hash.

See [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-3/), read the comment on round 1, technical question 1.

I found the same kind of comment written at many other places as well.

Comment: Define "print vertically" and describe your hashmap solution and please also link to the places that talk about doubly linked lists

Comment: "Given a character string, display the characters that appear more than once in that string." you iterate `char` by `char`, you use a `map` of `char,int`, you feed all `char`s to the `map`, in the end you print every key that has more than 1 occurence. Of course in C++ you use a `map` but any associative container will do.

Comment: `5 4 3 6 7 8 9` is not sorted. If I sort it and build a tree, I have now idea how you get to `6 4 5 7 8 3 9`

Comment: @NiklasB. why do you need to sort it? Just fill in the levels. Consider it as level order traversal.

Comment: @user2714358: The 6 has to be the root and the three has to be the leftmost node. Not sure what you mean by "level order"

Comment: @NiklasB. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertical-sum-in-a-given-binary-tree/ this might help understand the vertical traversal concept.

Comment: I see, so the tree is not a search tree. I was confused about that, and you should include an ASCII art of your tree into your question and define the concept of a "column" more clearly, because it is ambiguous

Comment: I think your approach is good. No need to change it up if it works. A hash map is the most obvious and clean way to solve this IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the interviewer probably meant is to pass a linked list down the tree and give each node a pointer to the list element that represents its column.

Just imagine the linked list to be infinite in both directions, you can easily extend it whenever you hit an end. Every item of the list is in turn a list of nodes:

```
function traverse(tree_node, list_node):
    if tree_node is NIL:
        return
    list_node.add(tree_node)
    traverse(tree_node.left, list_node.prev)
    traverse(tree_node.right, list_node.next)
```

Comment: Think this is right. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MukulJain The algorithm would output `[[n2], [n1,n3], [n4]]` in this case, which seems correct to me.

Comment: Can someone please explain this since I'm not able to get a clear picture of this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my double-linked-list based solution in Objective-C:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface ListNode : NSObject

+ (ListNode *)nodeWithValue:(id)value next:(ListNode *)next previous:(ListNode *)previous;

@property (nonatomic, strong) ListNode *next;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ListNode *previous;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id value;
@end

@implementation ListNode

+ (ListNode *)nodeWithValue:(id)value next:(ListNode *)next previous:(ListNode *)previous
{
    ListNode *node = [[ListNode alloc] init];
    node.value = value;
    node.previous = previous;
    node.next = next;
    return node;
}

@end


@interface TreeNode : NSObject

+ (TreeNode *)nodeWithValue:(id)value left:(TreeNode *)left right:(TreeNode *)right;

@property (nonatomic, strong) TreeNode *left;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TreeNode *right;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id value;
@end

@implementation TreeNode

+ (TreeNode *)nodeWithValue:(id)value left:(TreeNode *)left right:(TreeNode *)right
{
    TreeNode *node = [[TreeNode alloc] init];
    node.value = value;
    node.left = left;
    node.right = right;
    return node;
}

@end

ListNode *verticalTraversal(TreeNode *node, ListNode *list)
{
    if (!node) {
        return list;
    }

    [((NSMutableArray *)list.value) addObject:node.value];

    ListNode *head = list;
    if (node.left) {
        if (!list.previous) {
            list.previous = [ListNode nodeWithValue:[NSMutableArray array] next:list previous:nil];
        }

        head = verticalTraversal(node.left, list.previous);
    }

    if (node.right) {
        if (!list.next) {
            list.next = [ListNode nodeWithValue:[NSMutableArray array] next:nil previous:list];
        }

        verticalTraversal(node.right, list.next);
    }

    return head;
}

void verticalPrint(TreeNode *root)
{
    ListNode *list = [ListNode nodeWithValue:[NSMutableArray array] next:nil previous:nil];
    ListNode *head = verticalTraversal(root, list);
    ListNode *next = head;
    NSInteger level = 0;
    while (next) {
        NSArray *array = (NSArray *)(next.value);
        NSLog(@"%li: %@", level, [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
        next = next.next;
        level ++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        TreeNode *tree = [TreeNode nodeWithValue:@1
                                            left:[TreeNode nodeWithValue:@2 left:[TreeNode nodeWithValue:@4 left:nil right:nil] right:[TreeNode nodeWithValue:@5 left:nil right:nil]]
                                           right:[TreeNode nodeWithValue:@3 left:[TreeNode nodeWithValue:@6 left:nil right:nil] right:[TreeNode nodeWithValue:@7 left:nil right:nil]]];

        verticalPrint(tree);
    }
}
```